# Write a program that asks the user for up to 10 integers (it could be fewer); using arrays, and for loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

Write a program that asks the user for up to 10 integers (it could be fewer); stop prompting when the user enters zero. Then list the numbers in reverse order. Use the following example run as a guide:

```
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 11
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 33
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 55
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 77
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 99
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 0
    Your numbers in reverse order are: 
    99, 77, 55, 33, 11
```

below is my current code and can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main( ) {
int max = 10;
int num = 1;
int userVal[max];
int i = 0;


while(num <= max) {
  cout << "Enter a number (0 to stop): ";
  cin >> userVal[i];
  cout << userVal[i] << endl;
  if(userVal[i] == 0) {
     break;
  }
  ++num;
}
cout << num << endl;
cout << "Your numbers in reverse order are: " << endl;
for(i = num; i >= 0; --i) {
  cout << userVal[i];
  if(i < num - 2) {
     cout << ", ";
  }
}

return 0;
}
```

below is the output i'm getting obviously as stated above i want to numbers to print in reverse

```
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 11
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 33
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 55
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 77
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 99
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 0
    6
    Your numbers in reverse order are: 
    6553532600-6638791760, 4197268, 0, 0,
```

Comment: You never increment `i` in your first `while`, you could just do `num - 1` too.

Comment: Side note, do not use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: the for loop goes one iteration too far as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your while loop, you are using i to assign the values in the array, you need num instead. Second, num should be set to zero so that the first element of the array is filled. Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main( ) {
int max = 10;
int num = 0;
int userVal[max];
int i = 0;


while(num <= max) {
   cout << "Enter a number (0 to stop): ";
   int number;
   cin >> number;

   cout << number << endl;
   if(number == 0) {
      break;
   }

    userVal[num] = number;
    ++num;

}
cout << num << endl;
cout << "Your numbers in reverse order are: " << endl;
for(i = num; i >= 0; --i) {
   cout << userVal[i];
   if(i < num - 2) {
       cout << ", ";
  }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use `else` when you `break` in the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

First: You use two different variables - `num` and `i` - but you only increment the num variable. Better:

```
int num = 0; // start with 0 - this is the number read initially: nothing...
while(num < max) // need to use < instead
    std::cin >> userVal[num]; // can use your counter now as index, too...
```

However, you have to adjust your outputting loop accordingly:

```
for(int i = num - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

Second: You want to print a comma always - unless for the last index (0); so:

```
if(i > 0)
    std::cout << ", ";
```

Finally: You should declare max const or constexpr. C++ does not support variable length arrays on the stack. Normally, your compiler should complain about `int userVal[max];` (maybe it accepts it this time as it recognizes max never being changed - but that's not C++ standard).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all y'alls help the below code is what i came up with its a bit of a combined bit of each of your suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main( ) {
  int max = 10;
  int num = 1;
  int userVal[max];
  int i = 0;


  while(num < max) {
   cout << "Enter a number (0 to stop): ";
   int number;
   cin >> number;
   cout << number << endl;

   if(number == 0) {
     break;
   }
   userVal[num] = number;
   ++num;
  }
  cout << "Your numbers in reverse order are: " << endl;
  for(i = num - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    cout << userVal[i];
    if(i > 1) {
     cout << ", ";
    }
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
 }
```

i received the below output

```
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 11
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 33
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 55
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 77
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 99
    Enter a number (0 to stop): 0
    Your numbers in reverse order are: 
    99, 77, 55, 33, 11
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your indexing in the input loop.